# Please re-open "What is this open, vertical rectangular symbol?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question was closed as needing details/clarity. The information needed -- the piece from which the symbol in question came -- was already present, but "hidden" inside the image description. I've edited to clarify.

[What is this open, vertical rectangular symbol?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/110307/what-is-this-open-vertical-rectangular-symbol)

Comment: Note that this was reopened without any moderator intervention. I'd argue that simply casting a vote to reopen was enough.

Comment: @Richard Why "argue"? Was it inappropriate of my to post this in addition to voting to re-open? I was thinking that potential re-open voters might see this.

Comment: Sorry, "argue" wasn't mean to convey anything negative! Perhaps more in line with my intent would be "I wonder if simply casting a vote to reopen was enough."

Comment: Do note that when you vote to reopen a question, it will put it into a review queue where others can decide whether or not to reopen, and this queue is watched by other users. Once the post leaves the queue, the final outcome of the review can be seen in its timeline (the "clock" link under the voting and bookmark buttons). Only if that page shows a completed review of "Leave Closed" should you make a post here, to dispute the outcome of the review. In this case, your question [was reviewed in favor of reopening](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/62847).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick bookkeeping post: the question was reopened.